# Check if list contains any dict keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
d = {('shot',): ['V'], ('I',): ['NP']}
s = ["I", "shot"]
s1 = ["I"]
s2 = ["shot"]

print(str(tuple(s,)))
print([i in d for i in tuple(s,)])
print(bool(set(tuple(s,)).intersection(d)))
print(d[tuple(s1,)])
print(d[tuple(s2,)])
for i in set(tuple(s,)).intersection(d):
    print("Element "+i+" was found.")
```

Suppose I have a dict like aforementioned with each key being a tuple. Why is this the result:

```
('I', 'shot')
[False, False]
False
['NP']
['V']
```

Instead of this:

```
('I', 'shot')
[True, True]
True
['NP']
['V']
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Why `tuple(s,)` and not just `s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `I` or `shot` are keys in `d`, so both will be `False`. When you're creating the tuple from the list, each value in the list is used to create the tuple:

```
>>> tuple(["I", "shot"], )
('I', 'shot')
```

So when you're iterating over that list in your list comprehension:

```
[i in d for i in tuple(s,)]
```

What you're effectively doing is:

```
for i in ('I', 'shot'):
  if i in d:  # this will be 'I' in the first iteration, 'shot' in the next
      ...
```

Since neither of `I` or `shot` by themselves are keys, the result is `False`. The keys *actually* used in your dictionary are tuples, not strings (which is what you end up looking for).

However, what you might have wanted to achieve instead (since the `tuple(s, )` conversion doesn't do anything useful), is to look up a tuple with the string as the first element in the dictionary instead of iterating over it:

```
>>> [(i, ) in d for i in s]
[True, True]
```

To sum it up:

```
>>> 'I' in d
False
>>> 'shot' in d
False
>>> ('shot', ) in d
True
>>> ('I', ) in d
True
```

The last two examples create a tuple and then checks if that tuple is a key in the dictionary.

The same confusion about the keys and their values might also be the cause for your issue with `set`, but you'd want to be more explicit there - use `d.keys()` if you want an iterator that only gives you the keys in the dictionary and then intersect the two sets as you find necessary to achieve what you want.